# Yii 2 sort results by ASC or date

Tags: sorting, yii2

Essentially i have a table with data from my $dataProvider.

Now i can do this in my controller for example for putting.

```
$dataProvider->sort = array('defaultOrder' => [
    'name' => SORT_ASC
]);
```

So when the page is submit it can change, however i want to create two buttons on top of my table. So if you clicked on the button "date" It should display all the data in the current table in date order.

Now i dont want this to cause a page submission because then the results will come back different, as you can receive the data from searching different fields/categories etc...

So how can i make a button that when clicked will order the data by date.

Answer (score 0):

add the column date to your gridview and click the column title, Yii2 gridView do this behaviour by default

Comment: yes but as a requirement of a client i need to create 2 buttons.

Comment: however i need this to not submit the page

Comment: You don't need submit nothing, it's all on view

Comment: so when i search by category and get back all the related data. The i click a button <?php echo $sort->link('judgement_date');?> which should sort it.

However it then refreshed the page and sorts all of the data , not the data i got back from my search criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using JQuery. Here is a plug-in for client-side sorting tables with links outside the table: 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Example usage: 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-trigger-sort.html

Comment: this will not work as i need to sort by date which is in the database and related to a row however not actually put into the row at all.

Comment: So add the data, but don't display the row:
    style="display:none;"